# Can't type on input field in React after close then open it again

Tags: reactjs, forms, framer-motion

I have created a search box using a form input tag in react, I use Tailwindcss and Motion Framer for handling the animation. The search box will not appear until I click a button search and it will be closed after I click the Xmark button. I still can type on the input when the first try I open the search box, but after I close and open it again I can't type anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTOcB.gif)

```
{/* Login and Search Button Start */}
<div className="hidden md:block">
  {!isSearchOpen && (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        className="md:flex md:items-center md:gap-3"
      >
        <button
          onClick={() => setIsSearchOpen(!isSearchOpen)}
          className="cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-between gap-2 w-32 px-3 h-8 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 border border-solid border-gray-200 rounded-lg"
        >
          <span className="text-green-900 font-medium">Search</span>
          <MagnifyingGlassIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-green-900" />
        </button>
        <LoginButton />
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )}

  {isSearchOpen && (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0,
        }}
        animate={{
          width: "auto",
          opacity: 1,
        }}
        exit={{
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0,
        }}
        className="md:flex"
      >
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Search for workshops, articles, and videos"
            type="text"
            className="md:w-96 md:px-3 md:mr-3 md:h-7 md:bg-gray-300 md:border-solid md:border-gray-200 md:rounded-lg md:text-sm"
          />
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => setIsSearchOpen(!isSearchOpen)}>
          <XMarkIcon
            onClick={() => setIsMobOpen(!isMobOpen)}
            className="md:h-7 md:w-7 md:text-green-900 md:cursor-pointer"
          />
        </button>
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )}
</div>
{/* Login and Search Button End */}
```

I expected that I still can't type when the search box closed and opened again.

Comment: Hey there, I was not able to reproduce it can u create some codesanbox. It will be a great help

Comment: my bad, I use onClick={() => setIsMobOpen(!isMobOpen)} on the Xmark icon, I shouldn't use that. Thank you for trying to help, I really appreciate it.